# Implementing the right conditions for a yum command for centos5 in Ansible

Tags: linux, centos, yum, ansible

I'm currently working with a centos5 host and I have to install some packages with yum.. unfortunately, as far as I know, centos5 doesn't support Ansible's yum module so I have to use the 'command' or 'shell' modules and 'hard code' everything by myself.

My question is.. what are the conditions I should implement to make a command/shell behave like Ansible's yum module and make it as much 'indepotent' as possible?

For the moment this is what I came up with:

#### When installing/updating a package

```
- name: INSTALL (C5) - Install package
  ansible.builtin.command:
    cmd: yum -y install <package>
  register: output_install
  changed_when: '"Installing:" in output_install["stdout"] or "Updating:" in output_install["stdout"]'
  failed_when: output_install["stdout"] is regex("No package.*available")
```

#### When removing a package

```
- name: UNINSTALL (C5) - Remove package
  ansible.builtin.command:
    cmd: yum -y remove <package>
  register: output_remove
  changed_when: '"Erasing" in output_remove["stdout"]
  failed_when: "No Packages marked for removal" in output_remove["stdout"]'
```

Do you guys have any suggestion or have already dealt with this problem?
Thank you very much.

Comment: a side note: both centos 5 and 6 have long been EOL'ed.

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov I'm already aware of that, trust me. 
I'm just looking for solutions/people who have the same problem or for someone who used Ansible "back in the days" to tell me how they used to manage this situations since unfortunately upgrading those systems isn't possible.